# transition between view in iOS without navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, swipe, transition, gestures

I need get a smaller code of transition method between view in iOS/ but without navigation controller and any buttons(it's for swipe gesture)

How to be in this situation?

Comment: Use another segue. Try modal.

Comment: huh...it will be very great if modal case working in my situation!!!

I can't find any example in network of this realization!!!

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you mean... Have you tried a modal segue and that doesn't work? You don't need a navigation controller for a modal segue.

Answer (score 0):

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Actualy i solve my problem by this code 
and use navigation controller =(